# Store csv file in array removing first column [Python]

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I want to store a csv file in an array in python removing the first column. In order to store it I just write these 2 lines of code

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
def csvToArray():
    data = genfromtxt('SP500Index.csv', delimiter=',')
    return array
```

and it worked. From this point how can I get rid of the first column?

Comment: If you happen to know the number of columns you're working with (`num_cols`), then you can directly get the columns you want through the `genfromtext` method: `data = genfromtxt('SP500Index.csv', delimiter=',', usecols = range(1,num_cols))`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the usecols parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the numpy.delete function. Add it to the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def csvToArray():
    data = np.genfromtxt('SP500Index.csv', delimiter=',')
    data = np.delete(data, 0, 1) # the first input is the array, second is
                          #   which row/column to delete, third
                          #   determines if it is row (0) or column (1)
    return data #not sure why it had array before
```

Numpy's `delete` documentation is  [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).